# Validation email form not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, validation, email

I am trying to build a form that will validate a field upon a checkbox being checked. It works fine in all browsers except for IE. Any suggestions on making it work in IE also?

```
<form id="serviceForm" action="MAILTO:myemail@me.com" onSubmit="required(this);" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
        <label for="AgencyRequesting">*Agency Requesting Facility:</label>
        <br />
        <input id="AgencyRequesting" required="required" maxlength="50" name="Agency Requesting Facility" size="50" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="AgencyContact">*Agency Contact:</label>
        <br />
        <input id="AgencyContact" required="required" maxlength="50" name="Agency Contact" size="50" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="AgencyPhone">*Contact Phone Number:</label>
        <br />
        <input id="AgencyPhone" required="required" maxlength="14" name="Agency Phone Number" size="14" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />*Area of Facility Requesting: 
        <br /><p style="font-size:.8em;padding:0;">(If interested in reserving the range for your agency, please complete the form below and submit to us.  Once we  receive it, we will email you confirmation and availability.)<br />
            (** Submitting this form does NOT secure your reservation on our facility, it is merely a request.)</p>
        <br />

<!--Gymnasiun checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->  
<input id="gym" name="Gymnasium" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Gymnasium
    <br />
    <span id="togggym" style="display:none;">
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="gymStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                    <input id="gymStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="gymEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                    <input id="gymEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="gymStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                    <input id="gymStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="gymEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                    <input id="gymEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
            </span>
    </span>
<!--Classroom checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="classroom" name="Classroom" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Classroom
    <br /> 
    <span id="toggclass" style="display:none;">
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="classStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                    <input  id="classStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="classEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                    <input id="classEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="classStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                    <input id="classStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
            </span>
            <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
                <lable for="classEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                    <input id="classEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
            </span>
    </span>
<!--Upper checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="upper" name="Upper Track" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Upper Track
<input id="lower" name="Lower Track" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Lower Track
<input id="both" name="Both Upper and Lower Track" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Both
    <br /> 
    <span id="toggupper" style="display:none;">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="upperStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="upperStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="upperEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="upperEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="upperStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="upperStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="upperEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="upperEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--Lower Checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
    <span id="togglower" style="display:none;">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="lowerStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="lowerStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="lowerEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="lowerEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="lowerStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="lowerStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="lowerEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="lowerEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--Both checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
    <span id="toggboth" style="display:none;">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="bothStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="bothStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="bothEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="bothEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="bothStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="bothStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="bothEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="bothEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--East Pistol Checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="east" name="East Pistol" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />East Pistol
    <br />
    <span id="toggeast" style="display:none;">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="eastStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="eastStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="toggeast" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="eastEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="eastEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="toggeast" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="eastStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="eastStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="toggeast" style="display:inline;"
            <lable for="eastEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="eastEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--West Pistol Checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="west" name="West Pistol" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />West Pistol
    <br /> 
    <span id="toggwest" style="display:none">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="westStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="westStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="westEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="westEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="westStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="westStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="westEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="westEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--Rifle Checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="rifle" name="Rifle" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Rifle
    <br /> 
    <span id="toggrifle" style="display:none">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="rifleStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="rifleStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="rifleEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="rifleEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="rifleStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="rifleStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="rifleEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="rifleEndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--360 Range Checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="360" name="360 Range" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />360&#176 Range
    <br /> 
    <span id="togg360" style="display:none">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="360StartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="360StartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="360EndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="360EndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="360StartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="360StartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="360EndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="360EndTime" maxlength="7" name="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>
<!--Sims Trailers Checkbox
    *********************************************************************************************************-->
<input id="sims" name="Sims Trailers" type="checkbox" value="Checked" />Sims Trailers
    <br /> 
    <span id="toggsims" style="display:none">
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="simsStartDate">*Start Date:</lable>
                <input  id="simsStartDate" maxlength="10" name="Start Date" size="10" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="simsEndDate">*End Date:</lable>
                <input id="simsEndDate" maxlength="10" name="End Date" size="10" /><br /><br />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="simsStartTime">*Start Time:</lable>
                <input id="simsStartTime" maxlength="7" name="Start Time" size="7" />
        </span>
        <span id="togg2" style="display:inline;">
            <lable for="simsEndTime">*End Time:</lable>
                <input id="simsEndTime" maxlength="7" mane="End Time" size="7" /><br />
        </span>
    </span>

    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="description">Comments:</label>
    <br />
    <textarea name="Comments" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />* denotes required fields
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
/*Gym
    ********************************************************************************/
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#gym").change(function(){              
            $("#togggym").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#gymStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#gymEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#gymStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#gymEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#gymStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#gymEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#gymStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#gymEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#gymStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#gymEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#gymStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#gymEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*Classroom
    *******************************************************************************/
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#classroom").change(function(){              
            $("#toggclass").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#classStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#classEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#classStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#classEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#classStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#classEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#classStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#classEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#classStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#classEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#classStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#classEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*Upper
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#upper").change(function(){              
            $("#toggupper").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#upperStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#upperEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#upperStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#upperEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#upperStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#upperEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#upperStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#upperEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#upperStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#upperEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#upperStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#upperEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*lower
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lower").change(function(){              
            $("#togglower").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#lowerStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#lowerEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#lowerStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#lowerEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#lowerStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#lowerEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#lowerStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#lowerEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#lowerStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#lowerEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#lowerStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#lowerEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*Both
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#both").change(function(){              
            $("#toggboth").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#bothStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#bothEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#bothStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#bothEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#bothStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#bothEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#bothStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#bothEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#bothStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#bothEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#bothStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#bothEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*East Pistol
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#east").change(function(){              
            $("#toggeast").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#eastStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#eastEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#eastStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#eastEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#eastStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#eastEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#eastStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#eastEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#eastStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#eastEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#eastStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#eastEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*West Pistol
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#west").change(function(){              
            $("#toggwest").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#westStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#westEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#westStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#westEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#westStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#westEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#westStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#westEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#westStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#westEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#westStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#westEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*Rifle
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#rifle").change(function(){              
            $("#toggrifle").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#rifleStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#rifleEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#rifleStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#rifleEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#rifleStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#rifleEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#rifleStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#rifleEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#rifleStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#rifleEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#rifleStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#rifleEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*360 Range
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#360").change(function(){              
            $("#togg360").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#360StartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#360EndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#360StartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#360EndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#360StartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#360EndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#360StartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#360EndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#360StartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#360EndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#360StartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#360EndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
/*Sims Trailers
    *******************************************************************************/
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sims").change(function(){              
            $("#toggsims").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#simsStartDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#simsEndDate").toggleClass("required");
            $("#simsStartTime").toggleClass("required");
            $("#simsEndTime").toggleClass("required");

    if(this.checked){
           $("#simsStartDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#simsEndDate").attr('required','required');
           $("#simsStartTime").attr('required','required');
           $("#simsEndTime").attr('required','required');
      }
      else{
           $("#simsStartDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#simsEndDate").removeAttr('required')
           $("#simsStartTime").removeAttr('required')
           $("#simsEndTime").removeAttr('required')
      }

        });
    });
```

The JavaScript is probably insanely out of hand, but I'm very new to programming in it and still have a lot to learn.
Thanks for any and all help, and if there is a better way to write this, I'm open to every suggestion.

**Update-Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandon7575/JcMZK/3/) to the form in action

Comment: Can you be more specific please, what is no working?

Comment: When the submit button is pressed in IE an email opens and it has no content, but when the submit button is pressed in Firefox, Opera, and Chrome the email is populated with all of the fields info.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are new to validating forms using Javascript/jQuery.

I would suggest using a jQuery plugin such as  jQuery.validate to validate your forms front end. The plugin will ensure validation works cross browser including Internet Explorer.

Suggested articles:

1. [BASIC JQUERY FORM VALIDATION EXAMPLE (2MINS)](http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/)

Also, don't forget that front end is validation is only half the battle, you will also need to validate backend! To ensure security and validity of data passed through to the form data handling script.